# simple jsp page is not working in tomcat 7.0 using eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

web page showing `http status 500`.
what to do?

here is stacktrace,

```
Nov 22, 2013 4:49:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/jsftesting] threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade cannot be cast to javax.portlet.PortletContext
at com.sun.faces.portlet.FacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.TomahawkFacesContextFactory.getFacesContext(TomahawkFacesContextFactory.java:107)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.prepareFacesContext(FacesServlet.java:235)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: What code caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some problem while starting the Server.
Please elaborate about which type of project you created and structure of the project as well.

Comment: It is just simple jsp page with three to four input fields still it is static and doent connected to any bean or other page

Comment: Are you creating Simple DynamicWebProject for any other project

Answer (score 0):

It is done it  was problem with libraries I put same libraries in tomcat lib folder as well as in in webcontent/lib . so when  I removed these from one folder which were additional so i found my project runing